# How can I clear form values after successful form submission

Tags: symfony

How can I clear form values after successful form submission?

These didn't help:

- [How to clear field value with Symfony2 forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014747/how-to-clear-field-value-with-symfony2-forms)
- [Clear form values after successful submit](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=26868&p=97772)

**CONTROLLER:**

```
namespace Car\BrandBundle\Controller;

use Car\BrandBundle\Entity\BrandEntity;
use Car\BrandBundle\Form\Type\BrandType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class BrandController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = $this->getFrom();

        return $this->render('CarBrandBundle:Default:brand.html.twig',
                array('page' => 'Brand', 'form' => $form->createView(), 'brands' => $this->getBrands()));
    }

    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() != 'POST')
        {
            return new Response('Only POST method is allowed');
        }

        $form = $this->getFrom();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $submission = $form->getData();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $brand = new BrandEntity();
            $brand->setName($submission->getName());

            $em->persist($brand);
            $em->flush();

            $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('brand'));
        }

        return $this->render('CarBrandBundle:Default:brand.html.twig',
                array('page' => 'Brand', 'form' => $form->createView(), 'brands' => $this->getBrands()));
    }

    private function getFrom()
    {
        return $this->createForm(new BrandType(), new BrandEntity(),
                array('action' => $this->generateUrl('brandCreate')));
    }

    private function getBrands()
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CarBrandBundle:BrandEntity');
        $brands = $repo->findAll();

        return $brands;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You simply need to unset both form and entity objects. Then, create new, clean instances so they are available in your template.
Personally I prefer to do it only when the form is properly validated.

```
if($form->isValid()){

  // persisting and flushing the entity

  unset($entity);
  unset($form);
  $entity = new Entity();
  $form = $this->createForm(new EntityType(), $entity);
}
```

Works for me.
Cheers.

Comment: Works for me, too (3.2). Thanks!

Comment: It works correctly, just comment that it is not necessary to perform the unset.

Comment: This is unnecessary, you only have to RETURN the return value of redirect: `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('brand'));`

Answer (score 34):

**Resetting symfony form when same page handles the submission**

In Bazyl's method creating another form after unsetting current form may be unnecessary task. I suggest to redirect to same page because symfony documentation ([handling-form-submissions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms)) also shows an example which redirects to another controller.

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
        return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
    }
```

I have added sample sources to [GitHub](https://github.com/lahiiru/SymfonyFormResetting)

Comment: That do the job perfectly, unsetting form and entity didn't worked for me.

Comment: @tokam What is the symfony version you are using? and what was the output?

Comment: I am using Symfony > 3.0
The request still contained the post data, so if I redirect to the reference action, it will last in an infinite loop

Comment: @tokam I tested in Symfony 3.1 and working well. Find my sources here https://github.com/lahiiru/SymfonyFormResetting

Comment: return $this->redirectToRoute('route_name');

Comment: After 2 years, This answer should be accepted as the good answer. It's more clean that unset(variable) then recreate

Comment: @Samine, it's July 2021, and return $this->redirect($request->getUri()); works perfectly in Symfony v.5.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is related but when your form is valid, you do `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('brand'));`. The issue is `$this->redirect()` simply creates a redirect response that your controller **must** return in order to be taking into account. In other words, just do `$this->redirect()` in the middle of a controller does nothing (except intantiating a `RedirectResponse` which be garbage collected by PHP).

Answer (score 1):

If using twig templates, you can just clear it there.
Example:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.yourFieldNameHere, { 'value': '' }) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```